# How merge works in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I posted a questions [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988638/pandas-python-flag-transactions-across-rows) and got the answer.

Could you explain how the join `final_df = pd.merge(df, temp_df.reset_index(), how="left").fillna(0)` works? I am getting the correct results, but I don't understand how the join happens. There are no common columns between df and temp_df.

Working code as below:

```
    d = {'emp': ['a',   'a',    'a',    'a',    'b',    'b',    'b',    'c',    'c',    'c',    'c' ], 
     'date': ['1',  '1',    '1',    '1',    '2',    '2',    '2',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3' ], 
     'usd':[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,     11 ], 
     'expense type':['Car Mileage',     'Car Rental',   'Car Rental - Gas',     'food',     'Car Rental',   'Car Rental - Gas',     'food',     'Car Mileage',  'Car Rental',   'food',     'wine' ],
     'zflag':['1',  '1', '1',   ' ',' ',' ',' ','2','2',' ',' ' ]
     }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)



        df
    Out[253]: 
       date emp      expense type  usd zflag
    0     1   a       Car Mileage    1     1
    1     1   a        Car Rental    2     1
    2     1   a  Car Rental - Gas    3     1
    3     1   a              food    4      
    4     2   b        Car Rental    5      
    5     2   b  Car Rental - Gas    6      
    6     2   b              food    7      
    7     3   c       Car Mileage    8     2
    8     3   c        Car Rental    9     2
    9     3   c              food   10      
    10    3   c              wine   11   


temp_df = df.groupby(["emp", "date"], axis=0)["expense type"].apply(lambda x: 1 if "Car Mileage" in x.values and any([k in x.values for k in ["Car Rental", "Car Rental - Gas"]]) else 0).rename("zzflag")
temp_df = temp_df.loc[temp_df!=0,:].cumsum()
final_df = pd.merge(df, temp_df.reset_index(), how="left").fillna(0)
```

## Update 1:

`temp_df` doesn't have an index and it is a series. So I am not sure how the join can occur on the index as suggested in the comment.

```
temp_df
Out[335]: 
emp  date
a    1       1
c    3       2
Name: zzflag, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Ni_Tempe What is happening is that pd.merge with out parameters is merging on common column names such as 'emp' and 'date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge` without `on` or `index` parameters is joining on common column names:

[Per Docs in pandas API on pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas-merge) look at 'on' parameter:

> on : label or list
>       Field names to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. If on is
>       None and not merging on indexes, **then it merges on the intersection of
>       the columns by default**.

```
d = {'emp': ['a',   'a',    'a',    'a',    'b',    'b',    'b',    'c',    'c',    'c',    'c' ], 
     'date': ['1',  '1',    '1',    '1',    '2',    '2',    '2',    '3',    '3',    '3',    '3' ], 
     'usd':[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10,     11 ], 
     'expense type':['Car Mileage',     'Car Rental',   'Car Rental - Gas',     'food',     'Car Rental',   'Car Rental - Gas',     'food',     'Car Mileage',  'Car Rental',   'food',     'wine' ],
     'zflag':['1',  '1', '1',   ' ',' ',' ',' ','2','2',' ',' ' ]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
temp_df = df.groupby(["emp", "date"], axis=0)["expense type"].apply(lambda x: 1 if "Car Mileage" in x.values and any([k in x.values for k in ["Car Rental", "Car Rental - Gas"]]) else 0).rename("zzflag")
temp_df = temp_df.loc[temp_df!=0,:].cumsum()
a = temp_df.reset_index()

all(pd.merge(df, a) == pd.merge(df, a, on=['emp','date']))
```

Output:

```
True
```